# Render date and time fields for datetime column in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I have read and tried a lot but didn't find a solution.

The task is simple:

I have a column scheduled_at of the format datetime.

Instead of having one field in my form for datetime, I want to split it into two fields: one for the date and one for the time. In my table I want to keep it as one datetime field.

So at some point I have to join the date and time to datetime. Since I have a validation for datetime in my model, I can't do this joining in the controller.

I have tried a few things:

- Create attr_accessors (but I can't find a way to join date and time in the model)
- Find some plugin to solve this via JS on the browser side
- https://github.com/shekibobo/time_splitter, but it won't join the values either

I imagine that many apps have this issues but still can't find a solution on the internet.

Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: why can't you join this in the controller? you can allow both the date and time param and then do just that: join them in the controller

Comment: Yes, that what I did before. but I have some validation rules to run on this datetime. As far as I understand it's always preferable to put those things into the model...

Comment: Yes the validation should be in the model, but you can combine params in the controller before adding the fields to the object (and therefor triggering the validation)

Comment: Of course...the validation runs only when save() is called...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [before validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback to combine the two fields into one datetime field before rails performs its validation.

Example:

```
class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.your_field = do_stuff
  end

end
```

You can read more on [Active Record Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) in the rails guide.